# Python print length OR getting the size of several variables at once

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, printing, size

In Python, if I `print` different data types separated by commas, they will all act according to their `__str__` (or possibly `__repr__`) methods, and print out a nice pretty string for me.

I have a bunch of variables like `data1, data2...` below, and I would love to get their total approximate size. I know that:

- not all of the variables have a useful `sys.getsizeof` (I want to know the size stored, not the size of the container.) -Thanks to Martijn Pieters
- the length of each of the printed variables is a good enough size estimate for my purposes

I'd like to avoid dealing with different data types individually. Is there any way to leverage a function like `print` to get the total length of data? I find it quite unlikely that something like this is not already built into Python.

```
>>> obj.data1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> obj.data2 = {'a': 1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
>>> obj.data3 = u'have you seen my crossbow?'
>>> obj.data4 = 'trapped on the surface of a sphere'
>>> obj.data5 = 42
>>> obj.data6 = <fake a.b instance at 0x88888>
>>> print obj.data1, obj.data2, obj.data3, obj.data4, obj.data5, obj.data6
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2} have you seen my crossbow? trapped on the surface of a sphere 42 meh
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
printlen(obj.data1, obj.data2, obj.data3, obj.data4, obj.data5, obj.data6)
109
```

I know most of you could write something like this, but I'm mostly asking if Python has any built-in way to do it. A great solution would show me a way to `return` the string that `print` prints in Python 2.7. (Something like `print_r` in PHP, which I otherwise feel is wholly inferior to Python.) I'm planning on doing this programmatically with many objects that have pre-filled variables, so no writing to a temporary file or anything like that.

Thanks!

As a side-note, this question arose from a need to calculate the approximate total size of the variables in a class that is being constructed from unknown data. If you have a way to get the total size of the non-callable items in the class (honestly, the total size would work too), that solution would be even better. I didn't make that my main question because it looks to me like Python doesn't support such a thing. If it does, hooray!

Comment: Would a profiler be more helpful?

Comment: @doctorlove Potentially, but this is really just an intermediate step to see if my average object is small enough that I can afford to move them all into a database. It would be really nice to have a class method that just gave me the approximate size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A great solution would show me a way to return the string that print prints in Python 2.7."

This is roughly what `print` prints (possibly extra spaces, missing final newline):

```
  def print_r(*args):
      return " ".join((str(arg) for arg in args))
```

If you run in to lots of objects that aren't `str`-able use `safer_str` instead:

```
  def safer_str(obj):
      return str(obj) if hasattr(obj,"__str__") else repr(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `sys.getsizeof()` is **not** the method to use to determine printed size. A python object *memory* footprint is a poor indicator for the number of characters required to represent a python object as a string.

You are looking for `len()` instead. Use a simple generator expression plus `sum()` to get a total:

```
def printlen(*args):
    if not args:
        return 0
    return sum(len(str(arg)) for arg in args) + len(args) - 1
```

The comma between expressions tells `print` to print a space, so the total length `print` will write to `stdout` is the sum length of all string representations, plus the whitespace between the elements.

I am assuming you do not want to include the newline `print` writes as well.

Demo:

```
>>> printlen(data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6)
136
```

Comment: I know that sys.getsizeof doesn't represent the number of characters required. I'm planning on moving this data to a database if it proves feasible, and as such just want to know the approximate size of a lot of objects in some measurable way, whether it be printed length or memory footprint. Spaces will be negligable enough. (I'm assuming that Python's footprints are reasonable). The problem with using `len` and `str` is that not all of my objects are easily cast-able to strings, and I was looking for a solution that didn't depend on different handlings of different data types.

Comment: Neither string length nor `getsizeof()` will be proper indicators. You need to use the actual representation the **database** uses to measure database footprint.

Comment: For example, a `dict` is a container. `sys.getsizeof()` returns the memory requirement *for that container only*, not the contents. And that size is dependent on your platform; a pointer on a 32bit architecture is smaller than a pointer on a 64bit platform.

Comment: Databases use their *own* representation, and you'll need to a) figure out what database datatypes are going to represent your Python objects, and b) how many database objects it'll take to represent one Python object (can be variable and more than 1) and c) how much space those database types will take up in the database.

Comment: Then comes the fact that Python containers use `repr()` for their contents, add commas, and add whitespace. The `repr()` of a python string will use escape codes to represent certain characters; `\n` for a newline is *two* characters for one byte. `\x0a` is *four* characters for a single byte, etc.

Comment: And custom classes are by default only represented by their name and memory address. Nothing is said of their attributes, which could run anywhere between 0 and all available memory.

Comment: I don't think I was clear enough in my question, and I'll edit it in a moment. The exact reason I didn't use `sys.sizeof()` is that it will not give me useful data, while `print` will. It will obviously not give me the exact size needed in the db, but it will give me a ballpark estimate so I can know whether I can afford a database in the first place!   (And, of course, thank you for all of these useful tidbits)

Comment: @rogaos: if your data requirements are such that you cannot afford a database, you cannot afford the program, full stop.

Comment: Hah, perhaps a bit of hyperbole. I'm interested to know how big these million or so objects are so I know about how much it will cost to store them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should now do it correctly:

```
def printlen(*args):
    return sum(map(len, map(str, args)))
```

For objects which do not support the `str(obj)` function. You could replace the `str` with a self made function or lambda:

```
def printlen(*args):
    return sum(map(len, map(lambda x: str(x) if hasattr(x, '__str__') else '', args)))
```

Comment: This won't work for objects that do not have a length. The custom class and the integer in the sample do not have length.

Comment: Good point. I didnt read the question properly either as he wants the length of the printed strings

Comment: @ikkuh thanks. What about variables that I can't cast so easily to strings? Like a unicode string that has unexpected characters, or a custom class that doesn't take kindly to that cast. That's why I'm looking for a solution that basically piggybacks on top of print.

Comment: You could write your own str function. Something like `def my_str(obj):  if hasattr(obj, "str") return str(obj) else: return 0`. The printlen function then needs to be changed to `my_str` instead of `str` of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the length you can use this:

```
printlen = lambda *x: print(sum(len(str(i)) for i in x))
```

usage:

```
printlen(obj1, obj2, ..)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an object structure and you want to know how much does it require to store it, you could also `pickle`/`cpickle` the object and use that number as a measure, and to also to store the data into database.